# I should think you'd have

Tags: american-english, should

> -When you going back to kindergarten, Otis?" some one had asked.
>
> -"Me? Day Bernice gets her hair bobbed."
>
> -"Then your education's over," said Marjorie quickly. "That's only a bluff of hers. I should think you'd have realized."

*Source:* Bernice Bobs Her Hair by F. Scott Fitzgerald

I don't understand why the girl used "should think you'd have done" in the example. I understand that 'You would have realized' belongs to the third conditional. But why was it used with "should think".

Comment: Emphasis on the part of Marjorie. She is surprised Otis did not realise Bernice was bluffing. Or according this [this](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/should) to make it less blunt, but I am not sure I agree. Depends of tone of voice

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that this whole passage is written in non-standard English.

Answer (score 7):

*I should think you'd have realized* is not a conditional sentence. *Should* has a tentative meaning here, that is, the speaker uses it to express a degree of uncertainty that would have been absent in *I think you realized*.

Comment: Thank you, Barrie, for your answer. But why was "would have" used? Why wasn't "I should think you realized" enough?

Comment: It’s because it continues the hypothetical meaning. In saying _I should think_, the speaker speculates about what the other person might have done. Although, as I said, this isn’t a conditional sentence, there is an implied condition in its second part. What is going through the speaker’s mind is something like _I should think you'd have realized (if you weren't so stupid)_.

Comment: Does this question exemplify the putative 'should'? See  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/224111/50720